# how to store return values from a function into column matrix (octave)

Tags: matlab, octave

While calling a function inside a for loop I need to store all return values into a column matrix nx1 if n is number of times loop iterates:

```
for (i = 1:n)
        function(arg);
end
```

After storing these values I need to get top five values as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
res = zeros(n,1);
for (i = 1:n)
        res(i)=function(arg);
end
```

Allocation before loop is required to be sure that you have column matrix instead row.

**Edit**:

Answer for last question: After storing these values I need to get top five values as well.

You can use sort function to receive best values:

```
res=sort(res);
result=res(1:5)
```

Comment: What if res has two columns say nx2 and I want to sort based on second column ?

Comment: @rakesh.pandit Octave and Matlab have function sortrows to make sorting based on entire row. In your case: sortrow(res, 2) is answer.

Comment: By default sortrow sorts in ascending order. What to change to print the output in descending order ?

Comment: @rakesh.pandit From matlab documentation:  If an element of column is positive, the MATLAB software sorts the corresponding column of matrix A in ascending order; if an element of column is negative, MATLAB sorts the corresponding column in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your argument `res` depends on the index `i`, i.e. `result(i) = yourfunction(arg(i))`, you can use the more compact expression:

```
  result = arrayfun(@yourfunction,arg);
```

.